# MFMailComposeViewController: issues with UITextField and UIAlertController after dismissal

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I have two issues after usage of `MFMailComposeViewControlle`r in my application:

1. After the `MFMailComposeViewController` is dismissed, the `UITextField` text on my initial `ViewController` is cleared
2. When attempting to display a `UIAlertController` to indicate a `MFMailComposeResult`, it fails to display giving a error in the log.

For issue 1: This is my `MFMailComposeViewController` code. It is an action of a `UIAlertController` (with `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`).

```
    UIAlertAction *email = [UIAlertAction
                        actionWithTitle:@"Email the link"
                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                        handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                        {

                            // composes new mail message with link
                            NSString *messageBody = self.link.text;

                            MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
                            mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
                            [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];


                            // customises UI to match application
                            [[mc navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                            [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:^{
                                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
                                [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
                            }];

                            [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                        }];
```

For issue 2: this is my code for displaying an appropriate `UIAlertController` for each relevant `MFMailComposeResult`.

```
- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:{

            UIAlertController *alert=   [UIAlertController
                                         alertControllerWithTitle:@"SearchMe"
                                         message:@"The composition of this email has been cancelled."
                                         preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction *done = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:@"Done"
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                   {
                                       [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                   }];


            [alert addAction:done];
            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

            [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


    }

            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:{

            UIAlertController *alert=   [UIAlertController
                                         alertControllerWithTitle:@"SearchMe"
                                         message:@"The composition of this email has saved as a draft."
                                         preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction *done = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:@"Done"
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                   {
                                       [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                   }];


            [alert addAction:done];
            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

            [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


        }

            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:{

            UIAlertController *alert=   [UIAlertController
                                         alertControllerWithTitle:@"SearchMe"
                                         message:@"The composition of this email has been sent."
                                         preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction *done = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:@"Done"
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                   {
                                       [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                   }];


            [alert addAction:done];
            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

            [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        }


            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        {

            UIAlertController *alert=   [UIAlertController
                                         alertControllerWithTitle:@"SearchMe"
                                         message:@"The composition of this email has failed. Please try again."
                                         preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction *done = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:@"Done"
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                   {
                                       [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                   }];


            [alert addAction:done];
            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

            [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }



            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

The error given in the log is this:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x14ed58b90> on <ViewController: 0x14ee1f7f0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Comment: While just MFMailComposeViewController and a UIAlertView can do all these, and which also would be little more memory efficient than this why you are going for more complicated code.

Comment: @Rameswar Apple introduced UIAlertController in iOS 8, I figured I would use it for interest of the future, since UIAlertView will probably be depreciated soon (correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: Hey thanks. I didn't know that, as you said I checked the UIAlertView API and yes they are saying it will be deprecated soon. Okay I will check the UIAlertController and probably your code, if I got any solution then will let you know. Meanwhile if you figure out the problem and get any solution then please do share. And thanks for the information.